# NancyFx Override the default Bootstrapper ctor

Tags: c#, owin, nancy

I have implemented my own Nancyfx Bootstrapper.

```
    public class MyBoot : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
        {
            if(switch)
           {
               //some code here
           }
```

I want to send a bool parameter (switch)
to this Class either thru the Ctor or a Property but I am unsure where  the bootstrapper is called from. Can you send a paremeter from

```
    return WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://*:7002");
```

Comment: is a global variable, acting as a switch, an applicable solution? that's a very nasty solution though ... ;)

Comment: Yea just a temporary test